# How to bind partial function as method on Python class instances

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, functional-programming

I want to bind this function as a method on some class:

```
def foo_method(msg, self):
    print self.prefix + msg
```

This works:

```
class A(object):
    prefix = 'msg: '

A.foo = lambda *args: foo_method('hello', *args)

A().foo()
# => msg: hello
```

This, however, does not:

```
from functools import partial

class B(object):
    prefix = 'msg: '

B.foo = partial(foo_method, 'hello')

B().foo()
# => TypeError: foo_method() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

The first example appears to be bound correctly, whereas the second does not.

Why?

Comment: Interesting. Investigating this now. I hope this is just an experiment you're playing around with and you're not actually trying to dynamically add partially applied methods to classes.

Comment: You don't need the `setattr` here. `A.foo = lambda # ...` also exhibits this behavior.

Comment: I’d venture this is some strange interaction due to lambda being a proper function and partial being a Callable (it’s actually implemented as a class).

Comment: @BaileyParker Yeah, I was guessing it had something to do with partial not being a function, I just haven't been able to find an explanation why that matters. Maybe it's something in the object model that I don't understand?

Comment: So it's somewhere in the self binding in `__getattribute__`. `A().foo` produces `<bound method <lambda> of ...>>` and `B().foo` produces `functools.partial(<function foo_method at ...>, 'hello')`. So it looks like in `B` `__getattribute__` doesn't self bind. To get an answer you have to delve into the world of metaclasses.

Comment: @BaileyParker FWIW, I _was_ actually trying to do this. I'm working on a Flask-Admin view, where I want to add some actions (http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_actions/), all of which share 99% of functionality and only differ in name and a string argument. I did solve it differently, but this was the first approach that sprang to mind and now I'm intrigued! :)

Comment: @BaileyParker Awesome - do you happen to have a pointer for me where I should look in the Python docs or source to get clued up about this? Do I have to slog through https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html or do you a more accessible place?

Comment: Probably won't be there. This is a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) thing. From Raymond's wording here it sounds like only functions and lambdas will be bound. You can confirm that the binding must be done at the time `__get__` is called, because `A.__dict__` and `B.__dict__` just store whatever is given to them (as expected). I'm digging through the C impl, but have yet to find where this check occurs.

Comment: @BaileyParker I think the relevant bits are https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ebc5ce42a8a9e047e790aefbf9a94811569b2b6/Objects/funcobject.c#L583 (this is the descriptor of `Function`) and https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e2f92de6a90ae11a6d8e01bd17fd88b005516835/Objects/classobject.c#L48 (setting up any callable as a method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: descriptors! Self-binding only happens during attribute access. There is no special language support for methods - they work using just function objects and descriptors.

Quoting https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods:

> Class dictionaries store methods as functions. [...] To support method calls, functions include the __get__() method for binding methods during attribute access. This means that all functions are non-data descriptors which return bound or unbound methods depending whether they are invoked from an object or a class. In pure python, it works like this:
>
> ```
> class Function(object):
>     def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
>         "Simulate func_descr_get() in Objects/funcobject.c"
>         return types.MethodType(self, obj, objtype)
> ```

Fascinating!

When accessing `A().foo`, the descriptor mechanism is invoked, calling `foo_method.__get__`, which returns a bound method:

```
A().foo
# => <bound method A.<lambda> of <__main__.A object at 0x10ca9c0d0>>
```

Since `functools.partial` does not implement `__get__`, it does not get bound:

```
B().foo
# => <functools.partial at 0x10caf3aa0>

hasattr(partial(foo_method, 'hello'), '__get__')
# => False
```

The question remains: if it's so simple, why *doesn't* functools.partial implement this as well?